# Cross reference formatting options

Tags: formatting, cross-referencing

I have got a quick question; I am writing a document with lots of sections and figures. Cross referencing works fine. So far so good. However, I would prefer when I reference something to have the figures and the sections in different formats.

For instance if I reference a section (provided tha appropriate labels are in place) I would like the output to be: `Section 4.3`

and when I reference a figure to have: `Figure 4-3`.

How should I go about it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please provide a bit more information about how the objects are currently "numbered". For instance, are `figure` objects already numbered `4-1`, `4-2`, `4-3`, etc (where `4` is probably the chapter number, correct?), or are they currently numbered as `4.1`, `4.2`, `4.3.`, etc? At any rate, you should have a look at the `cleveref` package, which provides nearly unlimited possibilities for low-level controls over the names and numbers used in cross-references.

Comment: All objects are currently numbered in the following format: `x.y`. What I need is to have sections referenced like `x.x` and figures referenced as `x-y`.

Comment: Do you maybe want to do a global reset of the numbering system of your figures from `x.y` to `x-y`? If you don't reset the numbering system, your readers may become confused by a figure's caption being numbered in `x.y` style but then being cross-referenced in `x-y` style.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can redefine `\p@figure` to produce the desired formatting (but this will only change the formatting of the string used for cross-references; the string used for captions will remain unaltered):

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@figure{\thechapter-\arabic{figure}\expandafter\@gobble}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
See figure~\ref{fig:test} in section~\ref{sec:test}...

\section{test}\label{sec:test}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption{Test Figure}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And combining this with the `cleveref` package, you can say something like this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\p@figure{\thechapter-\arabic{figure}\expandafter\@gobble}
\makeatother

\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}
\Crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
See \cref{fig:test} in \cref{sec:test}...

\section{test}\label{sec:test}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption{Test Figure}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Remarks:

1. I only used `[!ht]` as placement specifier just for this example; I am *not* recommending its usage.
2. As a personal opinion, this style introduces some level of inconsistency since we are referencing object `x.y` using a different string `x-y`. I would suggest you to reconsider this change.

For consistency's sake, I would prefer to change `\thefigure` so the strings used in the object numbering and the one used in the cross-reference will be the same:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thefigure{\mbox{\thechapter-\arabic{figure}}}
\makeatother

\crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}
\Crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
See \cref{fig:test} in \cref{sec:test}...

\section{test}\label{sec:test}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\caption{Test Figure}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I never meant to have different strings in between captions and cross references. I just wanted what you precisely describe in your second remark; Consistency between captions and references with different formats according to the kind of object referenced. Thank you.